# Errors when using entry widgets Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I am attempting to create a GUI that will convert metric measurements to Imperial or the other way round. However I am having trouble getting the variable from the `Entry` widget. My exact error is:

> Exception in Tkinter callback
>           Traceback (most recent call last):
>           File "C:\Python32\lib\tkinter__init__.py", line 1399, in __call__
>               return self.func(*args)
>           TypeError: valid() takes exactly 1 positional argument (2 given)

I have attempted using the `textvariable` method however I got much of the same error.
I am kind of new to this, so I am not sure what's wrong here. Help would be appreciated.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
class Buttons:
    def __init__(self,master,ImperialText,MetricText,metricVal):
        self.ImperialText = ImperialText
        self.MetricText = MetricText



        self.master = master
        self.Text1 = (ImperialText +'-'+ MetricText)
        self.button = Button(self.master,text= self.Text1,command = self.calc)
        self.button.grid(column = 0)
        self.button.config(height= 3,width=30)

    def calc(self):
        self.EntryStr = None
        self.entry = Entry(self.master)
        self.label = Label(self.master,text = 'Enter '+self.ImperialText)

        self.entry.grid(column = 1,row = 1)
        self.label.grid(column = 1,row = 0)

        self.entry.bind('<Return>',self.valid)

    def valid(self):
        print (str(self.entry.get()))

button1 = Buttons(root,'inches','centimetres',2.54)
button2 = Buttons(root,'miles','kilometres',1.6093)
button3 = Buttons(root,'foot','metres',0.3048)
button4 = Buttons(root,'yards','metres',0.9144)
button5 = Buttons(root,'gallons','litres',4.546)
button6 = Buttons(root,'pounds','kilograms',0.454)
button7 = Buttons(root,'ounces','grams',0.454)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Works without error for me in 3.6, make sure your indentations are correct.

Comment: @Nae are you _certain_ it works for you? It should be impossible to work correctly. Did you actually type something into an entry box and press return?

Comment: @BryanOakley ah no, you're right. I haven't tried the entry -.-'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you bind a function, tkinter always passes in an object that represents the event.

Change `valid` to be like this:

```
    def valid(self, event):
        print (str(self.entry.get()))
```

If you bind multiple widgets to the same function, the widget that received the event is `event.widget`. So, for example, you could rewrite your code like this to make it more reusable:

```
def valid(self, event):
    print(event.widget.get())
```

Additional documentation and examples for the `bind` method can be found here:

- http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-events-and-bindings.htm
- https://www.python-course.eu/tkinter_events_binds.php
- http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/binding-levels.html

Comment: Thanks this works well , I found it difficult searching for answers online what source did you use to learn tkinter?

Comment: @MatthewCudby Bryan is very knowledgeable of tkinter, check out his previous answers for lots of tkinter stuff :>

Comment: @matthew Bryan has been using Tcl/Tk for a long time, perhaps before Tkinter existed...

Comment: @MatthewCudby: I was a professional tcl/tk developer for several years starting back in the '90s; learning tkinter for me was just a matter of translating the tcl/tk commands to python.

Comment: @MatthewCudby: it's a normal python object, so yes, you can store it in another variable, pass it to another function, etc. I'm not sure why you would do that though, since it's really not useful any where else except in the context of servicing the event.